# Change Color with id + event condition, and not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

file with code javascript script.js

```
function style(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="orange";
}

var setlist = "sets.txt";

function loadXMLDoc(open){
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET",open,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

code in page, with not work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    if ((onclick="loadXMLDoc(setlist)" == true)){
        style("s");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>...
<dl>
<dt class="pro"><a onclick="loadXMLDoc(setlist)" id="s">Sets</a></dt>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

is the idea simple, when the condition is real the id ='s' it marks the text 'sets' in orange color, but not like(as) making it work, it is well you sentence it?

Comment: ok, lo que intento hacer no se puede porque el if no se ejecuta, pero porque?

Comment: Element with id: `p1` is missing. Check error console

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you have both a src attribute AND content in your script tag?

Comment: hablas español? tirame una explicacion

Comment: this problem is, not change color with condition is true, other work well.